# RewriteRule for matching URLs that do not start with specific prefix

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)tmpl=(component|system) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)t(p|emplate|mpl)= [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

When I access `/administrator/index.phpoption=com_component&task=ajax&format=raw&template=something` I get a 403 error.

How should I refactor these 4 lines to met the second condition (blocking `?tp=`, `?template=` etc. in all URLs, but beginning with `/administrator`?)

So `/administrator/index.php?option=com_component&task=ajax&format=raw&template=something` should be accessible, and `/index.php?option=com_component&template=something` should not.

Comment: what is the purpose of first rule? , is /index.php?tmpl=system should be accessible

Comment: Yes, it should. It's Joomla's peculiarities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negative [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) in your last rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)tmpl=(component|system) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)t(p|emplate|mpl)= [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!administrator/).+ - [F]
```

Comment: Thanks, that suits me. I used `RewriteRule ^/(?!administrator/).+ - [F]`